# hide page view controller dots just on the last page

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I want to hide page view controller indicator dots just in the last page ! my problem is that I can hide them in the last page but when i came back to the previous page i can see them again

here is my codes

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    self.pageVC.currentPage = pageViewController.viewControllers!.first!.view.tag

 if(viewControllers!.first?.view.tag == 4 ) {

    if (VCArr.last!.isViewLoaded)

    {
        print("Last Page")
        self.pageVC.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.pageVC.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.pageVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }



        if (VCArr.last!.isViewLoaded) {

    if(viewControllers!.first?.view.tag != 4 ) {

        self.pageVC.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightText
        self.pageVC.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.pageVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    }
```

Comment: Can you copy the full body of 'didFinishAnimating' ? The braces are unbalanced and the local function `refresh` is never called.

Comment: ok I deleted that because It was extra and doesn't need it any more

Comment: @ Michaël Azevedo I fixed the code

Comment: What is your expected behavior : hide the page control only on the last page and show it again when you scroll back, or once you reach the final page it is hidden definitively ?